# Jxbrowser: Get parent element of my element

Tags: dom, dom-node, jxbrowser

Is there any way directly get the parent element to find its attributes?
In my situation, I have a 
DOMElement img,I have to use functions

```
img.getparent().getparent().findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href"));
```

and the result is not accuarate since a parent node can find many same type of elements

```
<td>
<a href=""><img></img></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `DOMNode` to `DOMElement` and use it's `.getAttribute(String attr)`:

```
String href = ((DOMElement)(img.getparent())).getAttribute("href");
```